# Which design pattern to use - Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have three classes, `A`, `B` and `C` that extend from `D`. There are methods that are common to Class `A`, `B` and `C` which I have put in `D` where as there are certain methods that are common to `A` and `B`, `B` and `C` and `C` and `A`. I can add in another layer of inheritance i.e create another class `E` (put common methods for `A` and `B`), `D`  (put common methods for `B` and `C`) and `F`  (put common methods for `C` and `A`) but is there any design pattern relating to this?

Comment: It hurts my eyes to see A,B C D E A B C D everywhere, try to better demonstrate the issue.

Comment: The golden rule ("and pattern") is: favor composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use composition instead of inheritance. Just create other classes and let A/B/C have references to objects of these other classes. This way you are more flexible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Create small interfaces for the common behaviour and make the classes that need to share behaviour implement several interfaces. Then as has been suggested use composition to create classes to handle the various bits of functionality and then compose your instances of A B C D of the relevant classes to handle the functionality their interfaces define